# Tesseract: read from rectangle

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract

I'm using OpenCV to find the coordinates of number plate on the photo. Next I'm trying to send these coordinates to tesseract with the help of function `SetRectangle`.

```
...
CvRect rect;
rect=cvBoundingRect(contourLow, NULL); // finding rects among contours
Pix *image = pixRead("auto.jpg");
api->SetImage(image);
api->SetRectangle(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width, rect.height);
outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);    
...
```

The problem is that output is empty.

I'm sure that coordinates are right (checked it). Also if I set in tesseract the image of cutted number plate, it works properly.

So, how to set rectangle in a right form?

Comment: What's the data type of `api`? What does auto.jpg looks like? Can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

Here some codes what I used. It works fine. (Tesseract 3.02)

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
api->TesseractRect(_imgTemp.data,1,_imgTemp.step1(),0,0,_imgTemp.cols,_imgTemp.rows);
char* text = api->GetUTF8Text();
api->Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Include  the necessary headers tesseract/baseapi.h  and leptonica/allheaders.h to make it compilable on your machine.

```
char *outText;
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
// you can specify in input language as eng or fre or any other language the doc relates to
if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
    exit(1);
}

Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
api->SetImage(image);
//  SetRectangle(left, top, width, height)
api->SetRectangle(30, 86, 590, 100);
// Get OCR result
outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

// Destroy used object and release memory
api->End();
delete [] outText;
pixDestroy(&image);

return 0;
```